# Injecting data into every request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a situation where I need to generate an ID in javascript and put it into the masterpage somehow so that every time a request gets back to a controller I can get that value in the controller. I need this to work whether the request be from a form submit, or ajax call etc. In the controller I will have a property with a getter that pulls that value out of the masterpage somehow. Is this possible and how would it be achieved?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: Looks like some sort of custom authentication,  a transparent proxy could rewrite the URL's and add to them data, but it would not be an easy task

Comment: I have an ID generating in javascript that uniquely identifies every browser tab on a per user bases and I want to use this in my session management code on the back end but I need a way for it to always be available anywhere in the application.

Comment: One solution is to have cookie instead of value in the html

Comment: I thought about that but I believe cookies can not be managed on a per tab bases so the issue there would be if I had 2 tabs open I can no longer identify them separately because the cookie would be set to the value of the most recently opened tab. Correct me if I am wrong or there is a way to do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cookie in client and get you can get value from controller.

1. Write a base controller and extends that controller in your
   controller.
2. Write method in base controller to read cookie and store a variable. you can access the variable from derived controllers.

See below example:

```
  public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private string _id = null;
        protected string ID
        {
            get
            {
                var cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("ID");
                if (cookie != null)
                {
                    _id = cookie.Value;
                }

                return _id;
            }
        }
    }

        public class HomeController : BaseController
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var test = ID;

                ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

                return View();
            }
        }
```

// Place below code in your master page...

```
 <script>
        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        }
        setCookie("ID", "123456", 1);
    </script>
```

Comment: I had to add a window focus event to update the cookie when the user changes tabs but this solution ultimately got me what I needed, thanks!